# Check if we're in a GitHub Action / Travis CI / Circle CI etc. testing environment

Tags: python, github-actions, travis-ci, cicd, circleci

I would like to programmatically determine if a particular Python script is run a testing environment such as

- GitHub action
- Travis CI
- Circle CI

etc. I realize that this will require some heuristics, but that's good enough for me. Are certain environment variables always set? Is the user name always the same? Etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An environment variable is *generally* set for each CI/CD pipeline tool.

The ones I know about:

```
os.getenv("GITHUB_ACTIONS")
os.getenv("TRAVIS")
os.getenv("CIRCLECI")
os.getenv("GITLAB_CI")
```

Will return `true` in a python script when executed in the respective tool environment.

*e.g:*

- `os.getenv("GITHUB_ACTIONS") == "true"` in a Github Action workflow.
- `os.getenv("CIRCLECI") == "true"` in a CircleCI pipeline.
- ...

*PS: If I'm not mistaken, to identify the python script is being executed in `Jenkins` or `Kubernetes Service host`, the behavior isn't the same.*

Comment: Notice that if you are using tox it will remove environment variables. Google 'tox passenv' to understand its behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

I think the `CI` environment variable is defined in most environments

References for your 3 cases:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables
- https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables
- https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/CircleCI_Standard_Variables.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index